# TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: database, oracle, virtualbox

I got file `.ova` to restore virtual machine with installed and configured some Java EE application. Unfortunatelly, I have got some problem with connect to database (which is also preinstalled on that `.ova` file). I have no idea what it could mean and what should I do. Worth to say, my 2 other coworkers imported whole thing without trouble, they can connect to database.

Anyway on their virtual machine they have connection to the Internet, I don't, could it be the reason? Project use `hibernate` to connect to `localhost` with following details: **(but I get the same error with any other tool to connect db)**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>ad</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>ad</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Another difference between my hardware and them, my host system is `windows 7 x64`, their are  `windows xp`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see following services running in your virtual machine. 
run services.msc

- OracleXE
- OracleXEListener

If they are started and you can connect Oracle XE in your virtual machine (Use XE's link to start menu link for easy checking. )

Then your problem is with your network connection with VM and your Host machine. Look to coworker's  network connection settings. Virtual Box version is below.

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

- Not attached
- Network Address Translation (NAT)
- Bridged networking
- Internal networking
- Host-only networking
- Generic networking

After you do that , you need to change your connection string if you are trying to connect from Host to Virtual Machine. Give your Virtual Machine's IP in your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  in jdbc.properties change:

```
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

to this:

```
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
```

Answer (score 0):

The file should be .ora

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

It means you should have a started and fully functional oracle database instance on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but `ova` file was just a format in which I get the whole virtualn machine and that was ok...